# How do I ensure a text box is alphanumeric but without a leading digit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

My web application contains a text box for which I would like to restrict its input.  I would like to prevent the user from entering text that:

- Starts with white space
- Starts with something other than a digit
- Contains alphanumeric characters after the leading character.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: `prevent the user not start with...` really means `start with...` (double negation).

Comment: For questions like this one it would be good to provide matching/non-matching string samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to start with white space of alpha numeric: `[a-zA-Z]+`
Followed by 0 or more alphanumeric: `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Final expression

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 3):

For ASCII characters you could use:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$ // Note you don't need the "+" after the first character group.
                       // or...
(?i:^[a-z][a-z0-9]*$)  // Slightly shorter, albeit more unreadable, syntax (?i: ... ) makes the expression case-insensitive
```

If you want to match empty string just wrap the expression in "( ... )?", like so:

```
^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$
```

If you want to work in Unicode you might want to use:

```
^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Nd}]*$
```

Unicode w. empty string:

```
^(\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Nd}]*)?$
```

To read more about unicode possibilities in regex, see [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) on [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

**Edit**

Just collected all possibilities in one answer.